# MeteorJs and Masonry

Tags: javascript, meteor, masonry

I am using MeteorJS (So great :) ), to develop simple app. I want to use masonry, so I am using sjors:meteor-masonry package.

When I use this code everything works fine:

```
var itemsData = [
{
title: 'First item',
description: 'Lorem 1',
price: 20
},
{
title: 'Secounde item',
description: 'Lorem 2',
price: 40
},
{
title: 'Third item',
description: 'Lorem 3',
price: 10
},
{
title: 'Fourth item',
description: 'Lorem 4',
price: 10
},
{
title: 'Five item',
description: 'sit 4',
price: 10
}

];

Template.itemsList.helpers({
items: itemsData
});

Template.itemsList.rendered = function() {

    var container = document.querySelector('#main');
    var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    // options
    columnWidth: 200,
    itemSelector: '.item'
    });
};
```

But when I change part (code) for Template.itemsList.rendered to masonry don't work:

```
Template.itemsList.helpers({
items: function() {
return Items.find();
}
});
```

Any ideas ?

**EDIT**

*myapp/lib/collections/items.js*

```
Items = new Mongo.Collection('items');
```

And it is populated whit data from mongoshell. Data is ok, but masonry dont work.

**EDIT 2**

Masonry stops animating on screen resize and grid is not working as it should. No errors.

*myapp/client/templates*

```
<template name="itemSingle">
<div id="profile-widget" class="panel item">
<div class="panel-heading">
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="media">

                  <div class="media-body">
                     <h2 class="media-heading">{{title}}</h2>
                     {{description}}
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
               <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                  <a class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> 172</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> 34</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default highlight" role="button"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> 210</a>
               </div>
            </div>

</div>
</template>

<template name="itemsList">

<div id="main">
{{#each items}}
{{> itemSingle}}
 {{/each}}
</div>

</template>
```

Comment: Where are you defining the `Items` collection? And how?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on what exactly is not working? Are you getting data drawn to the screen but the Grid layout is messed up? Or, are the items not even drawing anymore? If it is the grid layout, can you post your itemsList template? And any error messages you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, without never finding the perfect solution. 
I tried to resolve with the `setTimout()` workaround  :

```
Template.main.rendered = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#container').masonry({
            columnWidth: 35,
            itemSelector: '.thumb',
            gutter: 10,
            isFitWidth: false
        });
    }, 1);  
}
```

Comment: No, I did not make it work. But Your help is much appreciated and for sure will help someone. Maybe is someting else on my code causing problem. I eventually droped from using masonry.